# Unexpected result calling collect method on a Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream, collect

I am trying to understand this Java Stream method

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
              BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator,
              BiConsumer<R, R> combiner);
```

The following code should give as a result 55 put instead 0 is printed out.
Can someone explain to me what is wrong and how to change it so that 55 is printed?

```java
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

// Create a supplier that returns a new mutable result container, in this case an Integer accumulator.
Supplier<Integer> supplier = () -> 0;

// Create an accumulator that adds the square of the current element to the result container.
BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> accumulator = (result, element) -> result += element * element;

// Create a combiner that adds two result containers together.
BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> combiner = (result1, result2) -> result1 += result2;

// Collect the results of the reduction operation into a single Integer value.
Integer sumOfSquares = numbers.stream()
                              .collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner);

System.out.println(sumOfSquares); // 55
```

Comment: I think it's because your `supplier` returns `0`. :)

Comment: But even changing supplier I don't get it right. The code returns what the Supplier returns

Comment: Of course the code returns what the supplier returns, bc you've used an immutable supplier. Note that `accumulator` is a `BiConsumer` - it doesn't return anything, bc you're supposed to modify the object referenced by the `result` parameter. But you can't modify an immutable `Integer`. Try supplying `AtomicInteger` (using `AtomicInteger.set(...)` as an accumulator) instead.

Comment: `result += ...` is not changing the value created by the supplier, only the parameter of the lambda (pass-by-value). (for example, use an one-element integer array instead of Integer: `Supplier<int[]> supplier = () -> new int[1];`, `BiConsumer<int[], Integer> accumulator = ...` and `BiConsumer<int[], int[]> combiner = ...` [or use `AtomicInteger`])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working on ints/Integer which are not mutable. Thus both, the accumulator and the combiner don't alter the result. Thus is stays 0.

You can avoid this problem by using a mutable object like AtomicInteger to do the operations and use a finisher to convert it back to Integer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    // Create a supplier that returns a new mutable! result container, in this case an AtomicInteger accumulator.
    Supplier<AtomicInteger> supplier = () -> new AtomicInteger(0);

    // Create an accumulator that adds the square of the current element to the result container.
    BiConsumer<AtomicInteger, Integer> accumulator = (result, element) -> result.getAndAdd(element * element);

    // Create a combiner that adds two result containers together.
    BinaryOperator<AtomicInteger> combiner = (result1, result2) -> {
        result1.getAndAdd(result2.get());
        return result1;
    };

    //Create a Finisher to get the Integer value
    Function<AtomicInteger, Integer> finisher = AtomicInteger::get;

    // Collect the results of the reduction operation into a single Integer value.
    Integer sumOfSquares = numbers.stream().collect(Collector.of(supplier, accumulator, combiner, finisher));

    System.out.println(sumOfSquares); // 55
}
```

Comment: To make this answer a little clearer, the code pasted by @Gyonder includes the comment: _// Create a supplier that returns a new mutable result container_ for the line `Supplier<Integer> supplier = () -> 0;` and that's where the answer can pretty much end: That is a falsehood, and thus, that is where the problem lies: OP mistakenly thought `Integer` is mutable when it is not.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the below code is not the answer you were seeking, nonetheless I believe it is a viable alternative solution.

- The `Stream<Integer>` is converted to an [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html).
- Each element of the `IntStream` is squared.
- All the [squared] elements are summed.

```java
numbers.stream()
       .mapToInt(n -> n.intValue())
       .map(e -> e * e)
       .sum();
```

The result is an `int` which you can convert to `Integer`, for example via [static] method [valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) in class `java.lang.Integer`.

Comment: This answer is more than viable, because it actually uses the correct tools! And `sum()` is a special case of reduction.

Comment: Correct solution but it can be simplified: `numbers .stream() .mapToInt(e -> e * e) .sum();`

Comment: @Chaosfire depends on if this a real world issue or some exercise to learn about Collectors. If this is a real world issue this solution is actually preferable though!

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code lies in the accumulator and combiner functions. In Java, the `BiConsumer` interface does not allow modifications to its parameters. When you use `result += element * element` or `result1 += result2`, you're trying to modify the values passed to the functions, which won't affect the original values.

To fix this, you need to use a mutable wrapper for your integer values. One way to do this is by using AtomicInteger. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

        Supplier<AtomicInteger> supplier = () -> new AtomicInteger(0);

        BiConsumer<AtomicInteger, Integer> accumulator = (result, element) -> result.addAndGet(element * element);

        BiConsumer<AtomicInteger, AtomicInteger> combiner = (result1, result2) -> result1.addAndGet(result2.get());

        AtomicInteger sumOfSquares = numbers.stream().collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner);

        System.out.println(sumOfSquares); 
    }
}
```